# Prototype JavaScript Ajax FIFO Queue

Tags: javascript, ajax, queue, prototypejs

I am writing a small web-based IM client, it works well however I am running into some issues.

The system is written with PHP and JavaScript, it uses authentication ID's which it puts on each page, when an ajax request is made it must include this authentication id. It's not a perfect system but I have no ability to change it.

the IM system is using periodic executors (Prototype library), there are 2 periodic calls it makes:

1. update contact list, since this doesnt change very often it gets updated every 30 seconds or so
2. check for new messages, this happens ever 5 seconds right now.

The issue is:

Periodic executor makes call to update contact list, uses the authentication id, the PHP side picks up that request, checks the authentication id, performs the task, returns the new list in JSON format along with a new authentication id to be used on subsequent requests.

If a check for new messages (timed) or sending of a message (not timed) occurs before the first function returns, the authentication id has not yet been updated. Therefore it uses the same authentication id as the previous request. That authentication id gets rejected by the PHP side of the system.

I'm looking for a way to serialize the requests into a FIFO style queue, meaning that any ajax request that's made (check messages, check contacts, send message) can be pushed onto the queue and will execute as soon as the previous ajax call is complete (100% done and returned)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to create a request queue class and use that to handle your ajax requests.  I'm sure you can find something made already by googling but here's one I found that should work for you:

http://positionabsolute.net/blog/2007/04/ajax-request-queue.php

You would have to replace all your ajax calls to use that new function but modifying a class like this should solve your problem.